# Problema ao desativar Backgroundworker

Tags: c#, thread, backgroundworker

Estou criando em meu form principal um objeto BackgroundWorker e tenho dois eventos de click, um para ativar e o outro para desativar o backgroundWorker, porem o metodo de desativar nao está funcionando.

```
BackgroundWorker worker;
public FrmPrincipal()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   worker = new BackgroundWorker();
   worker.DoWork += worker_DoWork;
   worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
   worker.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
   worker.ProgressChanged += worker_ProgressChanged;
   worker.RunWorkerCompleted += worker_RunWorkerCompleted;
}
```

Botao de ativar:

```
private Ativar_Click()
{
   worker.RunWorkerAsync();
}
```

Botao de desativar:

```
private Desativar_Click()
{
   worker.CancelAsync();
}
```

Evento do Do_Work:

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
     while(true)
     {
           ClienteBusiness.Inserir();
     }
}
```

Comment: Ele dá algum erro?

Comment: Não da nenhum erro e inclusive uso o Debug ele passa pelo worker.CancelAsync();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso acontece pois o `CancelAsync` apenas sinaliza o cancelamento, ainda é sua obrigação parar o que está sendo executado.

Basicamente o que o `CancelAsync` faz é setar o valor de `CancellationPending` como `true`, então você deveria mudar o seu loop para verificar se deve cancelar a operação.

```
private void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    while(!worker.CancellationPending)
    {
        ClienteBusiness.Inserir();
    }
}
```